# "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup" when combining "fixltx2e" and "preview" packages

Tags: floats, errors, two-column, preview

In a two-column document with `figure*` floats, where the `preview` package is set up to preview floats, compilation seems to fail if the `fixltx2e` package is loaded:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[active,floats]{preview}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}Test\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

The first error message seen reads:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.7   \begin{figure*}Test\end{figure*}

?
```

The error vanishes if `fixltx2e` is not loaded or if the `figure` environment is used.

My goal is to "preview" all figures in a two-column document, so that `\linewidth` is set up correctly within the environments. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to "fix" this while retaining `fixltx2e`? Is this package needed at all in a recent LaTeX installation?

Comment: The error happens when LaTeX is dealing with `\@endfloatbox`, which is modified by `fixltx2e`; the code of `preview` relies on the original kernel definition of `\@endfloatbox`. So I'm afraid it's a problem that should be solved on the `preview` side.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, this explains it. If you could make your comment an answer, I'd accept and send a bug report to David Kastrup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error happens when `\pr@\end@dblfloat` is being executed, which uses `\end@dblfloat`.

Let's compare the definitions of `\end@dblfloat` in the kernel and in `fixltx2e`:

### `latex.ltx`

```
\def\end@dblfloat{%
\if@twocolumn
  \@endfloatbox
  \ifnum\@floatpenalty <\z@
    \@largefloatcheck
    \@cons\@dbldeferlist\@currbox
  \fi
    \ifnum \@floatpenalty =-\@Mii \@Esphack\fi
\else
  \end@float
\fi
}
```

### `fixltx2e.sty`

```
\def\end@dblfloat{%
\if@twocolumn
  \@endfloatbox
  \ifnum\@floatpenalty <\z@
    \@largefloatcheck
    \global\dp\@currbox1sp %
     \expandafter\@gobble\end@float
  \fi
\else
  \end@float
\fi
}
```

As you see, the `\@largefloatcheck` command is followed by two quite different paths and this confuses `preview.sty` that relies on the kernel definition.

I don't see any way around this, unless `preview.sty` is updated to consider the case when `fixltx2e` is loaded.